# $X$ is locally compact iff $Y$ is locally compact, if there is a perfect map $f: X\to Y$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This question was part of my quiz and I was unable to solve it there and now tried again at home but unable to do it.

> Let $(X,T)$ and $(Y,U)$ be topological spaces and let $f: X\to Y$ be perfect map. Prove that $X$ is locally compact iff $Y$ is locally compact.

If $(X,T)$ and $(Y,U)$ are topological spaces  then a function $f: X\to Y$ is a perfect map if it is a closed continuous surjection with the property that for each $y\in  Y$, $f^{-1}(y) $ is compact.

Let $X$ be locally compact then for every $p \in X$ there exists an open set $U$ and a compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $p \in U$ and $U\subseteq K$.

Let $y \in Y$ be a point. there exists an set $Y'$ such that $ Y' =f^{-1}(y)$ is compact.

But I am at loss of ideas on how to prove $Y$ to be locally compact using more properties of $f$ being perfect.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

**If :** Let $y\in Y$ and $x\in X$ s.t. $y=f(x)$. Let $O_x$ a neighborhood of $x$ s.t. $\overline{O_x}$ is compact. One can prove that $f(O_x)$ is a neighborhood of $y$ s.t. $\overline{f(O_x)}$ is compact.

**Only if** Let $x\in X$. Let $O_{f(x)}$ a neighborhood of $f(x)$ s.t. $\overline{f(O_{f(x)})}$ is compact. Use the fact that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact for all $y\in O_{f(x)}$ to conclude that $\overline{O_{f(x)}}$ is compact.

Comment: Do you mind giving a detailed answer?

Comment: Which step is unclear ? @No-One

Comment: In only if we are given that $f^{-1}(y) $ is given  compact. Then how did you assumed that there must exist a nbd of x which is compact. You should be rigorious in this argument, I think.

Comment: In fact, what I wrote **if** is in fact the part **only if**, and same mistake for the other direction. I edited my answer, it should be more clear now.